# How to add header to output files in Java map reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to add a header to output files of hadoop map reduce based on the key passed to reducer. That is, I want the header to vary based on input that the reducer is processing. Is there a way to do this in MapReduce?

Comment: The old MapReduce API was replaced over a decade ago. New MapReduce is hardly used anymore so you really should consider upgrading. Have you looked at Apache Spark?

Comment: Previous answer where I suggested using Hive instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146435/2308683 But yes, SparkSQL can do the same